# Woocommerce Submit Order button not showing blockUI

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently having an issue where the Submit/Process Order button is not invoking BlockUI. The button action works fine and processes the order, however there is quite a delay once the button has been clicked. I'm concerned customers may click it a second time.

Comment: Really people? Three of you spent time correcting my grammar but nobody provides an answer? Wow.